# RMAN backup set, nothing else, how can I duplicate?

Tags: oracle, rman, duplication, disaster-recovery

I have what appears to be an RMAN backup set, it has been multiplexed in 32 files, each containing 2-3 dbf's inside. The backupset refers to an SPFILE file, but it was not included in the set, the backup piece containing just that file was not included.

I have no catalog, no infrastructure, and no way to connect to original database.  In addition the creators of the backupset have been evading my requests, I'm not sure why exactly but it appears to be business reasons.  In other words this is what I have, I cannot get anything better than what I've got right now.

I have an Oracle enterprise server, with the data in a backup directory.
What is the proper way to proceed?  Is it possible to duplicate from an auxiliary backup data TO a fresh blank database?  Meaning, is it possible to use an auxiliary as a primary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the sid name, you can copy a pfile over and edit it to change the values to match the database name. Make sure that you set B_CREATE_FILE_DEST to where you want the data files.

Then do a startup nomount on the database. In RMAN do "CATALOG START WITH '/full_path_to_your_backup';" You can then use DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT to convert the file names to be in the right directory.

You can then try to restore a control file. try list backup; and restore the oldest control file. Mount the database and try to restore the database.

It could be that the reason why the people who gave you the backup are avoiding you is because they know the backup is incomplete. But you have to try to restore what you can, then at least when you go back to them you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: When you say copy a pfile, do you mean from a blank freshly created DB? or did you mean from the unresponsive people whom which I previously stated were not providing one?

Comment: I mean take a copy of a pfile that you already have. Then find replace between the sid name from the original file and the sid name that you are restoring.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a method like this - Duplicate from RMAN Backup:

http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/duplicate-database-using-rman-11gr2.php#backup_based_duplication

Or look at the RMAN docs for "Backup-based duplication without a target connection":

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10643/rcmsynta020.htm#RCMRF126

They go through in detail what you need and what the process is.